# Deployment of ADA

Tags: deployment, ada

I have a software developed in ADA using GNAT GPS, I was wondering what is a publicly available software to create an installation package of my ADA software
for windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how it would be different from deploying any other program. (just don't forget to bundle Ada runtime with it; most probably libgnat.dll or something like that)

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look no further than your GNAT bin directory. AdaCore provides GPRinstall. Here's a couple Ada Gems on its use: [Part 1](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-158-gprinstall/), [Part 2](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-159-gprinstall-part-2/).